# How to perform a datamigration when moving from one-to-one to one-to-many

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

I'm using `south` to manage migrations and I've hit a corner. Basically I have the following setup:

**App1**:

```
class A(models.Model):
  # bunch of attributes
```

**App2**:

```
class B(models.Models):
  instance_a = models.OneToOneField(A, null=True, blank=True, 
                                    editable=False)
```

Now, I want to go from this to this:

**App1**:

```
class A(models.Model):
  instance_b = models.ForeignKey(B, null=True, blank=True)
```

**App2**:

```
class B(models.Models):
  # other attributes
```

My main issue is that I can't loose data. So basically at the end of the migration(s) all objects A that mapped previously to objects B should keep that mapping. As an example, if object A with id 7 was mapped to object B with id 8, by the end of this procedure this mapping should be retained.

I tried several things from schema migrations mixed with temporary place holders and data migrations. However I end up always in the same place, which is by the time the data migration is performed I no longer have the previous relations in order to access the correct attributes. So for example, B.instance_a is no longer available.

I would like your opinion on two things:

- First, is this viable at all using just south migrations.
- Second, how shall I proceed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after some time I got a procedure with `django-south` that might help others. The key was in south's `depends_on` feature (http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/Dependencies). I did it in 4 steps:

**First**:

- Create a placeholder for the values of the foreign key in model `A`.

So model `A` becomes:

```
class A(models.Model):
    instance_b_placeholder = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now just run `manage.py schemamigration app1 --auto`.

**Second**

- Create a datamigration so we can copy the values. The goal is to have the data duplicated in the db and later on rename the attributes and delete the old ones. Issue `manage.py datamigration app1 update_fields`. I chose to keep the datamigration in `app1`. If you don't do this just make sure it runs after the previous migration.

Here's the datamigration coded:

```
# Forwards:

for b in orm['app2.B'].objects.filter(instance_b__isnull=False):
        b.instance_a.instance_b_placeholder = b
        b.instance_a.save()

# Backwards:

for r in orm['app1.A'].objects.filter(instance_b_placeholder__isnull=False):
        r.instance_b_placeholder.instance_a = r
        r.instance_b_placeholder.save()
```

**Third**:

- Delete the field `instance_b` from model `B` and be sure to make the migration run after the one created in the previous step.

Model `B` becomes:

```
class B(models.Model):
     # etc...
```

Issue `manage.py schemamigration app2 --auto` and edit the migration adding the previous migration to `depends_on`:

```
depends_on = (
    ("app1", "<migration_number>_update_fields"),
)
```

**Forth step**:

- Rename the place holder. This is achieved by changing the name in the code and editing the migration. Editing is necessary because `south` tends to delete and add a new column, but we only want it to rename the column.
- This migration should run in last place, so I made it dependent on the previous one.

Here's the code:

```
depends_on = (
    ("app2", "<previous_migration_here>"),
)

# Forwards:

    db.rename_column('app1_a', 'instance_b_placeholder_id', 'instance_b_id')

# Backwards:

    db.rename_column('app1_a', 'instance_b_id', 'instance_b_placeholder_id')
```

So that's it. I don't know if there are so many other ways to do it, but at least this helped me.